# how to append input type file

Tags: jquery, html

in my html

if i change type to text it's fine but when i change it type file nothing happen when i click

```
<input type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*" >a
<input type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*" id="u_f">b<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btn1">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
```

Here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#u_f").append(" <input type='file' name='pic' accept='image/*' id='u_f' />b<br>.");
        // alert('hi');

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#u_f` element is an `input`, so you cannot `append()` any content to it. If you're attempting to add *another* file input, you can use `insert()`, `insertAfter()`, or any of the other DOM insertion methods:

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  $('<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" />b<br>').insertBefore(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*">a<br />
<input type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*">b<br />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btn1">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
</button>
```

Also note that I removed the `id` attributes as you would end up duplicating them with the added content, which would make the HTML invalid.

Comment: why you so fast always fast and furious

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
     $("#u_f").parent().append($("<input/>",{type:"file",name:"pic",accept:'image/*',id:'u_f'})).append("b<br>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btn1">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
</button>
<hr>
<input type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*" >a<br>
<input type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*" id="u_f">b<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to change your code according to below line

```
 $("#u_f").append(" <input type=\'file\' name=\'pic\' accept=\'image/*\' id=\'u_f\' />b<br>.");
```